# How to simulate samples from distribution of minimum of 3 distributions whose cdf are defined on different intervals.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, monte-carlo, simulation, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose, X,Y,Z are three positive independent variable.
The cumulative distribution of X is as follows:

\begin{equation}
    F_X(t) =
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{cc}
                F_1(t) & \mathrm{if\ } 0<t<\tau_1 \\
                F_2(t) & \mathrm{if\ }  \tau_1<t<\tau_2 \\
                F_3(t) & \mathrm{if\ } \tau_2<t<\infty \\
        \end{array} 
    \right.
\end{equation}

Siilarly Y and Z has distributions like this in the same intervals but are not identical to X.

Also, cumulative distribution function:

$$ F_1(t), F_2(t) \ and\  F_3(t) $$ are such function so that $$F_1(\tau_1)=F_2(\tau_1) $$ and $$F_2(\tau_2)=F_3(\tau_2)$$
T is the minimum of X, Y, and Z.
My question is: How to simulate T from X,Y and Z so that we can get the value of T as well as an indication of where it has come from? indication = 1 if the minimum has come from X, indication = 2 if minimum has come from Y, and indication = 3 if the minimum has come from Z. Sample size should be n, and it is not specific how many samples there should be between $\tau_{i-1} $ and $ \tau_{i}$.

I was trying to simulate 3 uniform distributions by cutting them $$ F(\tau_1), F(\tau_2) $$ but problem is that I am not getting the same number of samples in each boundary of the tau. If the sample size is 1, then it's easy, but when it's not 1 and not specific for different intervals, it's stuck.

For sake of simplicity i was doing for exponential distribution with different parameters.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand your goal here, but if we can sample data distributed according to the distribution of $X/Y/Z$ then we can just generate a sample from each, compute the minimum and save another variable that says which of the samples was the minimum.  If the question is how to generate i.i.d. samples with a given distribution, then under certain restrictions on $F_1,F_2,F_3$  we can use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) method.

Comment: Are the $F_i(t)$ easily invertible? Is $F_X(t)$ continuous?

Comment: It is not clear how you would have a continuous distribution made up of piecewise exponential CDFs, while discontinuous CDFs could lead to more than one value equalling the minimum

Comment: @Henry F_i(t) is easily invertible. Also F_X(t) is continuous.